# Kill process started with FullTrustProcessLauncher in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, process

I have UWP app which launches a background console app and they start communication through an app service. The problem I encountered is that I want to signal the console app to terminate by sending a request from the UWP app. Is there any way this could be achieved ? I have enabled the App Diagnostics capability for the UWP app. I have also tried to use the System.Diagnostics library, however I receive the following error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Retrieving information about local processes is not supported on this platform.'
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This blog post [here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/) has a fair bit of info about what you can and can't do with managing processes from a UWP app. As of that post, it doesn't look like you can terminate processes using the UWP APIs, and I don't think that's changed since then.

However, this functionality is supported in WinUI3 applications if you are able to migrate your application to v1.0 of the SDK.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will look into it.